# swapping rows of a list of numpy arays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a list of numpy arrays. I want to swap the rows to create a list of new numpy arrays of the same size as original list such that rows of the first array in the list should be the first rows of the new arrays, rows of the second array in the list should be the second rows of the new arrays, rows of third array to be the third row and so on.

For example, if the list of arrays is

```
 [array([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]], dtype=float16),
  array([[5., 6.],[7., 8.]], dtype=float16)]
```

The new list should be

```
 [array([[1., 2.], [5., 6.]], dtype=float16),
  array([[3., 4.],[7., 8.]], dtype=float16)]
```

Is there a better way to do it rather than looping through the arrays ?

Comment: did you think of different format rather then list of numpy arrays? for example? 3d-array.

Answer (score 0):

We can use [`numpy.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) for creating `numpy.array` from the list of arrays then we can use [`numpy.transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) or [`numpy.swapaxes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) for converting to what you want and at the end, we can use [`numpy.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) for converting to list of arrays.

```
lst_arr = [a, b]

# lst_arr
# [
#     array([[1., 2.],
#            [3., 4.]], dtype=float16),
    
#     array([[5., 6.],
#            [7., 8.]], dtype=float16)
# ]

tmp = np.transpose(np.stack(lst_arr), axes=(1, 0, 2))
# tmp = np.swapaxes(np.stack(lst_arr),0,1)

result = np.split(tmp.reshape(-1, len(lst_arr)),
                  indices_or_sections = len(lst_arr))
print(result)
```

---

```
[
    array([[1., 2.],
           [5., 6.]], dtype=float16), 
    
    array([[3., 4.],
           [7., 8.]], dtype=float16)
]
```